# Do I need an additional lockfile when locking access to a file in bash

Tags: bash, concurrency, locking

I am currently looking at locks in Bash. In the script I am working with I have a file that may be used concurrently by multiple invocations of the same or other scripts. In order to synchronize the access to the file I am using a lockfile:

```
(
   flock -x -w 10 200
   # do stuff with the file $DATAFILE
) 200>$LOCKFILE
```

This is taken from some examples I found online. However I am wondering if the additional `$LOCKFILE` is actually needed or if I can lock access to `$DATAFILE` directly:

```
(
   flock -x -w 10 200
   # do stuff with the file $DATAFILE
) 200>>$DATAFILE
```

Would this work, or is there some problem with using the file I am trying to synchronize access to as a lock file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock an existing file descriptor instead of creating a new one, and that descriptor can be the same one you use for your data file:

```
exec 200<>$DATAFILE
flock -n 200 || { echo "Already locked"; exit 1; }
# do your stuff with descriptor 200
flock -u 200
# optionally, close the descriptor
exec 200>&-
```

This also works with read only descriptors:

```
exec 200<$DATAFILE
```